# Which meaning of "but"? Or just wrongly noted example sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the Cambridge Dictionary's article ["the icing of the cake"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/icing-on-the-cake), the following example is given:

> I was just content to see my daughter in such a stable relationship but a grandchild, that really was the icing on the cake.

Even after checking all meanings of ["but"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/but) I cannot figure out which meaning of "but" is meant here. Rather it seems to me that the above example sentence is noted wrongly, and the right notation should be:

> I was just content to see my daughter in such a stable relationship.
>   But a grandchild *(=having a grandchild, moreover)*, that really was the icing on the cake.

Is my assumption right/wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I was just content" in this context implies that the writer might not dare for more than their daughter being in such a stable relationship, but the "but" says they got more in the form of a grandchild, which was the icing on the cake i.e. something that elevated an already positive situation.

Comment: So, was I right assuming that "but" is not a conjunction in the expression "(such) a stable relationship but a grandchild" but a conjunction in the greater sentence structure: "I was just content... but a grandchild (makes me even more content) ... was the icing on the cake"?

Comment: Yes you have understood it correctly.